# Proof related to vectors: collinear points, position vectors

Tags: vectors, education

I'm wondering if the following sentence is correct:

"Given 3 collinear points (A,B,C) and the relative distances (m and n), the position vector OC of the central point is m*OA+n*OB."

[image]

---

EDIT: mAB+nAB=AB --> m+n=1.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: When you say "relative distances", do you mean that $m+n=1$? Either way, make sure that your prediction handles the limiting case where $m=0$ and $n=1$.

Comment: Hello @ChrisCulter, yes you are right. I edited my question. Thank you for the revision.

Answer (score 2):

You have $m$ and $n$ reversed. The correct expression is:

\begin{align}
OC &= OA + mAB   \\
&=OA+m(OB-OA)   \\
&=(1-m)OA + mOB\\
&=nOA+mOB
\end{align}

If you can’t remember where the $m$ and $n$ go in this equation, it’s easy to check the cases $m=0$ and $m=1$.

Comment: Hello @bubba, both your and ChrisCulter answers are excellent, so I voted up them without privileging any.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, except that you have $m$ and $n$ backwards. When $m=0$, we want to get $C=A$,  so the correct expression is $C=nA+mB$. This equation expresses $C$ as an [affine combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination) of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Hello @ChrisCulter, both your and bubba answers are excellent, so I voted up them without privileging any.